# Redirecting all php file and error document to index.php except request of stylesheet, images, java script, ajax

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well this question is quite common and i also searched and tried many answeres, but i didnt get a proper format that can solve my problems.

What i want.

1. Redirect all error document (ie any non found file or directory request should be redirected to root file which is in my case - index.php)
2. Redirect all page request to root file (index.php) as a parameter ie if 
   someone enter a url like

**domain.com/directory_request/file_request**

then it should be treated as

**domain.com/index.php?directory=directory_request&file=file_request**

and request like

**domain.com/directory_request1/directory_request2/file_request**

then it should be treated as

**domain.com/index.php?directory=directory_request1-directory_request2&file=file_request**

1. All images, css, javascript, file should not be redirected to root files.
   One thing more i want all non-existing css, images etc should also be redirected to root file.

In short all requested url should be redirected to root file index.php with parameters as the request described earlier in point 2, except all EXISTING images javascript , css request.

i hope i clear my point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, in cases like this, it's best to direct all requests to your front controller and parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` inside of that file. This allows you to keep all of your rules and parsing in one place (as opposed to parsing URLs in .htaccess and routing requests in your front controller).

A simple rule like that could be (in your .htaccess file or httpd.conf):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` is telling Apache to only run the `RewriteRule` if the requested filename is not an actual file

Comment: I agree with you it's better using a front controller and parsing the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the php file.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually confused after reading so many responses from different user. And i think yes this could be the good possible way to do the task.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to use the `RewriteCond`'s to check if the requested directory/file exists.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
```

And then you can use these in front of each of your rules. To get it exactly like you want you can use as many rules as you want like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?directory=$1&file=$2
```